# How to completely backup all mysql databases

Tags: mysql, linux

My server crashed yesterday and now I have the hard disk mounted in a Linux live environment. How can I backup all the databases so I can copy them to the new server?

I don't know all of my database names so I can't use mysqldump for each one of them.

**EDIT:** I don't have and can't install the MySQL service.

Comment: Try `mysqldump5 --help` at the command line - it is in there.

Comment: Probably better suited over @ superuser?

Comment: Or maybe ServerFault

Comment: `mysqldump` is the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysqldump --all-databases > databasebackup.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to copy your files from `C:\xampp\mysql\data\DATABASE\` into your new database folder.

Comment: Can someone confirm this? I heard you can't just copy InnoDB databases.

Comment: @hans..how do you know whether Lholleman is using xampp?